# .Net How to compare generic typeinfo

Tags: generics, .net-4.0, typeinfo

I want to filter a collection of properties to find all properties that are of type [`EntityCollection<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354106.aspx) like so:

```
entity.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(EntityCollection<>));
```

The above code will always return no results because the properties will be of type `EntityCollection<TEntity>` where `TEntity` is an [`EntityObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx).

I've also tried using `EntityCollection<EntityObject>` with no success.

I don't care about the specific type of `TEntity`, I just want properties that are of type [`EntityCollection<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354106.aspx) regardless of the type of `TEntity`.

This seems like it should be simple, am I missing a trick here? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
           p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
```

Is that what you're after? Note that this won't find *subtypes* of `EntityCollection<TEntity>`.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that's exactly what I was after :-)